# bcrypt comparing problems (node.js)

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

So I am having issues getting bcrypt to compare passwords correctly. I generate the salt outside of all functions, hash it inside the register function, try to compare it in the login function. However, I am having issues, it will always produce that i put in the wrong password. I will be leaving out a lot of my code, to keep it readable.

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('mongodb');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const router = express.Router();

let error = {};

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

// register user
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = await userDb();

    // Checks for already existing users
    let userNameCheck = await newUser.findOne( { 'username':  req.body.username });
    let userEmailCheck = await newUser.findOne( { 'email':  req.body.email });
    if (userNameCheck) {
        Object.assign(error, {
            'usernameExists': 'Username already Exists',
        });
    }

    if (userEmailCheck) {
        Object.assign(error, {
            'emailExists': 'Email already Exists',
        });
    }
    // Check for illegal characters in username
    if (checkSymb(req.body.username) || checkLatin(req.body.username)) {
        illegalCharacters = true;
        Object.assign(error, {
            'illegalCharacters': 'Illegal Characters, please only alpha numeric!',
        });
    }

    if (userNameCheck || userEmailCheck || illegalCharacters) {
        res.status(201).send(error);
        return;
    } else {
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
        await newUser.insertOne({
            email: req.body.email,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: hash,
            },
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }    
        });
        res.status(201).send();
    }


});

router.post('/login', async (req, res)=> {
const currentUser = await userDb();

// Check blank
let emailBody = req.body.email.length;
let passBody = req.body.password.length;

if (!emailBody) {
    Object.assign(error, {
        'blankEmail': 'Email can not be blank!',
    });
}

if (!passBody) {
    Object.assign(error, {
        'blankPassword': 'Password can not be blank!',
    });
}

if (!emailBody || !passBody) {
    res.status(201).send(error);
}

// See if member exists
const doesExist = await currentUser.findOne({ 'email': `${req.body.email}` });
if (doesExist) {
    // if user exists check password
    let passGood = bcrypt.compareSync(doesExist.password, salt);
    if (passGood) {
        console.log('Login Successful');
        res.status(201).send();
    } else {
        console.log('Username or Password incorrect');
        Object.assign(error, {
            'wrongCredits': 'Username or Password incorrect',
        });
        res.status(201).send(error);
    }

} else {
    error = 'This user does not exist';
    console.log(error);
    res.status(201).send(error);
}
});
async function userDb() {
    const client = await db.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });

    return client.db('kog').collection('users');
};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to compare an existing password to see if it is correct. I know it is correct, as i am keeping it simple for testing reasons. I am not sure why the comparing is not working, and I know I need to compare the hash, but if I try to compare a new hash, it becomes a problem still.

Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule: There is no global salt. Every single user **must** get their own salt. Salt values are not secret. Store the salt in the DB when you create a new user record, and use the individual salt when calculating and comparing hashes. Change the salt when the user changes their password.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... and it was a dumb mistake:

From this: `let passGood = bcrypt.compareSync(doesExist.password, salt);`

To this: `let passGood = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, doesExist.password);`